# Spring MVC: How to get view-name in JSP?

Tags: spring-mvc

Is a way to access view name in JSP (`profile` in example below) or i need to add this name to model ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/account", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    return "profile";
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I  ran into this same problem recently. There could be an official way to solve this problem, but I couldn't find it. My solution was to create an interceptor to place the view name into the model.

My interceptor is very simple:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class ViewNameInModelInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        if (modelAndView != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("springViewName", modelAndView.getViewName());
        }
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }

}
```

And registering it in the spring config, is also pretty simple (using the namespace configuration):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="ViewNameInModelInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 9):

${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}

Comment: This should be flagged as answer !

Comment: I get requestScope is null, exception message is "cannot index into a null value"

Answer (score 3):

Just for people that will search for Thymeleaf solution:

```
${#httpServletRequest.getServletPath()}
```

Comment: Same as @Cyrils answer: Returns path instead of returned view name.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a view name in the jsp page as it shown below:

```
${pageContext.request.servletPath}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns: `/WEB-INF/pages/profile.jsp`, but need `profile`

Comment: sorry for that, I do not know an another way except that you already described in your initial message. btw, I always put the view name to the model when I do need it on my view