# Spring MVC: ModelAndView objects are not getting carried to the view

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am currently trying show variables from the controller into the view, the view is not showing them.

Thanks for any help!

UserController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("message", "added Var from controller");
    return "user/login";
  }
}
```

Also tried

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
modelAndView.setViewName("user/login");
modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello World");
return modelAndView;
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Login</h2>

  <p>This is my message: ${message}</p>
  <c:out value="${message}" />

</body>
</html>
```

Output

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Login</h2>

  <p>This is my message: ${message}</p>
  ${message}

</body>
</html>
```

My Spring servlet-context.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.controllers" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721518/el-expressions-wont-executed-in-tomcat-5-5-but-working-in-tomcat-6-0-20

Comment: thanks that worked
I had to edit web.xml
and change

    <web-app>

to

    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241754/spring-mvc-how-to-get-view-name-in-jsp