# spring mvc not working on cloudfoundry

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I have an application developted with spring-mvc. And I deploy the application to cloudfoundry.

Everything is alright in my local, but on cloudfoundry session objects is not rendered successfully.

this is my application

http://jelibo.final.cloudfoundry.com/

login credentials are : test / test

after login fallow "Hesabım" link on left menu.

I am trying to deploy my application both with the eclipse plugin and "mvn clean verify cf:update cf:restart"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about this discusssion

[Spring MVC: ModelAndView objects are not getting carried to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314404/spring-mvc-modelandview-objects-are-not-getting-carried-to-the-view)

My local is tomcat7; but cloudfoundy works on tomcat6. So the web.xml version must be version2.4 specification.

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-   app_2_4.xsd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have a space inside your expressions.
When I look at your source I see the following:

```
<font color="#777" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">${merc.merchantName }</font>
```

As you can see there is a space at the end of `${merc.merchantName }`

Try removing the space and have it as `${merc.merchantName}` and see if then works.

Comment: I remove the spaces before right brackets, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;`

Some times `import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;` gets auto imported by the IDE.